# Webpack shows wrong line of code where was an error

Tags: webpack

When I get an error in my code, in browser Webpack shows me wrong line, 
why it happens? [48 line shows webpack, 46 is correct.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x5c6.png)

webpackconfig:

```
const path = require('path');
const LiveReloadPlugin = require('webpack-livereload-plugin');

module.exports = {
  watch: true,
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    main: ['./js/main.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
  },
  plugins: [
    new LiveReloadPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Comment: line 48 of which file? your webpack config or of main.js? please note error lines won't probably be right because your scripts are probably bundled and possibly minified.

Comment: of ship.js
ya, I saw that in browser this file has 2 additional lines at the top by webpack, so 2 lines mistake, but can this lines be removed, or some options to webpack for correct line of error showing?

Comment: You can exclude the file from being bundled (removing any reference of the script file from your other sources or main.js) but otherwise I don't think you can tell webpack to ignore a syntax error. can you post the output of your log here, perhaps I can pick up something